# Filtering date intervals by 15 min in Tableau

Tags: tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

I have some fake account information that I am trying to learn Tableau on and need to be able to filter the date field (which is a timestamp mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss) by 15 minutes. There are around 1,000 records on any given day. I have two ways that could potentially work but don't know how to execute them.

**Ask #1:** Within those records I want to be able to throw a filter by that date but instead of a 'slide bar' is there a way to show the filter in a drop down format? I know that if I add the date field to the 'PAGE' space it gives me the drop down I want but when changing the dates in the page drop down, the data doesn't change, hence not filtering.

- **Side question:** What is the difference between the page and filter spaces in tableau UI?

**Ask #2:** Within these records, is there way to add another field/column that buckets these dates (timestamps) by 15 min? Picture idea link below. Thank you in advance!

[Tableau Sample Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34hs7.png)

Comment: Look at the functions date_part() and date_trunc() as models. Sounds like you need to write a calc that behaves similarly. As one step, you could use date_part() to extract the # of seconds, and then use the div() function to truncate to a multiple of 15, — then multiply by 15 to yield 0, 15, 30 or 45.

Comment: Did you try the formula in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by creating a calculated field `interval` with the following formula for classification

```
IF DATEPART('minute',[Timestamp])>=0
AND DATEPART('minute',[Timestamp])<15
THEN '0-15'
ELSEIF DATEPART('minute',[Timestamp])>=15
AND DATEPART('minute',[Timestamp])<30
THEN '15-30'
ELSEIF DATEPART('minute',[Timestamp])>=30
AND DATEPART('minute',[Timestamp])<45
THEN '30-45'
ELSEIF DATEPART('minute',[Timestamp])>=45
THEN '45-00'
ELSE NULL
END
```

[image: calculated field example]

and then use it to filter rows.

By the way, the pages shelf lets you break a view into a series of pages, I think that in your specific case you should use the filter pane and not the pages pane.